# Delete all related id from multiple tables in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I delete related id's from multiple tables.

For example:

I have an invoice table which stores all the headers and an invoice body table which stores all the details of the invoice and invoice footer which stores all the amounts of the invoice, and I want to delete my main part is to delete the main invoice table and all its related id's form multiple table.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the AppServiceProvider:

```
Invoice::deleting(function($invoice) {
    $invoice->footer()->delete();
    $invoice->body()->delete();
});
```

If the invoice is deleted, the event "deleting" will be fired and the related models will be deleted too.

Comment: Why in the AppServiceProvider? Wouldn't it be more convenient to add it in his/her model?

Comment: If i want to add it to my model or controller would it be the same code as above?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
Invoice::deleting(function($invoice) {
    $invoice->footer()->delete();
    $invoice->body()->delete();
});
```